# How do I instantiate several set objects to test the various constructors and methods of my Set Class?

Tags: c++

```
//Header File
#ifndef SET_H
#define SET_H

class Set
{
    private:
        int * set;
        int pSize;
        int numElements;
        static const int DEFAULT_SIZE=5;
    public:
        Set(int);
        Set(int [], int);
        Set(const Set&);
        ~Set();
        void setSet();
        void display();
};
#endif

// Member Implementation File
#include <iostream>
#include "Set.h"
using namespace std;

Set::Set(int SIZE = DEFAULT_SIZE) // Default Constructor
{
    pSize = SIZE;
    set = new int[pSize];
}
Set::Set(int arr[], int pSize)  // Set Constructor
{
    this->pSize = pSize;
    set = new int [this->pSize];
    for(int i =0; i < pSize; i++)
    {
        set[i] = arr[i];
    }
}
Set::Set(const Set &obj)   // Copy Constructor 
{
    pSize = obj.pSize;
    set = new int[obj.pSize];
    for(int i =0; i < pSize; i++)
    {
        set[i] = obj.set[i];
    }
}
Set::~Set()
{
    if(set != NULL)
        delete []set;
    set = NULL;
}
void Set::setSet()
{
    cout << "Please enter a set of integers" << endl;
    cin>> numElements;
    while(numElements> pSize)
    {
        int *arr = new int[pSize + DEFAULT_SIZE];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < pSize; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = set[i];
        }
        delete []set;
        set = arr;
        pSize = pSize + DEFAULT_SIZE;
    }
    for(int i =0; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number" << endl;
        cin >> set[i];
    }
}
void Set::display()
{
    cout << "{";
    for(int i =0 ; i < numElements; i++)
    {
        if (i == numElements - 1)
            cout << set[i];
        else
            cout << set[i]<< ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
}

//Main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "set.h"
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Set myInstance[];
    myInstance.display();



    return 0;
}
```

How do I create different instances of the array from the member implementation file into the main file? How do I specifically format the line of code with the class, object, and calling array? Would i need another for loop in the file with my statement? Please let me know.

Additionally, I also need a method to add a new element to an existing set and return {true, false} accordingly.By definition an element of a set cannot be
repeated, therefore, this method must first ensure that the element being
added is not already an element of the set. If the element cannot be
added, the method should return false to denote this. This method should be able to add a new element to the set even if the physical array is at capacity (i.e. number of elements equals the physical size) when the method is invoked.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your question is "how do I instantiate an object?"?

Comment: Don't waste your time with an array. Be indiscriminate and create a new object for each test. All you are likely to learn from an array is that you're missing a much needed assignment operator.

Comment: Well I know how to instantiate objects when there are no arrays but in this case, arrays are being used so I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: I added something like:

Comment: Set myInstance;

Comment: and it gives me the error: no matching function for call to Set::Set()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem 1

The declaration of `Set::Set(int)` and its implementation are not right.

You may not use default parameter values in the definition. They need to be in the declaration.

```
class Set
{
   ...
        Set(int SIZE = DEFAULT_SIZE); // Default Constructor
```

and

```
Set::Set(int SIZE) 
{
    pSize = SIZE;
    set = new int[pSize];
}
```

#### Problem 2

```
Set myInstance[];
```

is not correct syntax. If you want to create a single instance, use:

```
Set myInstance;
```

If you want to create an array of 10 instances, use:

```
Set myInstanceArray[10];
```